# Who should I call for plumbing upgrades?

Tags: plumbing

We need the hot/cold valves replaced for our washer and the kitchen sink/faucet replaced. Call a plumber or handyman?

Comment: Either. A half-skilled handyman can sweat a copper joint or assemble a compression fitting. They may even use Sharkbite stuff that requires neither.

Answer (score 1):

A handyman should be able to take care of the sink / faucet replacement, but I'd want a plumber replacing the valves.

If you've got a plumber coming anyway, they may do the faucet replacement, but probably not the sink replacement.